# Why does my external usb 3 DVD player play some DVD's but not others?

Tags: usb, dvd

I did buy an external usb 3 DVD player for my RPI 4. I plug it into my new usb 3 hub so that I pull power from the hub and not the Pi.  Oddly, it plays some DVD's but not others. I wonder why? How can I troubleshoot or resolve this issue please? What logs should I view and how do I view the logs please? I have VLC media player installed and that is what I have been using. Should I be using a different player? If so, which one? Thank you

Comment: do the DVDs play ok on a different player? ... do the DVDs have anything in common?

Comment: Do the player plays all DVDs connected to another computer?